# vue js sync modifier doesn't update the input value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a beginner question about sync modifier in vuejs. In my example, i want to change the value of inputs depending on focus event. The value is an Object `inputsData` and i'm getting it from the `app`. In `parent` i'm passing it to the `child` where it is rendering. I set an timer because i want to emit an server request. As you can see in the `handleFocusFromChild` Methode it change me the `dataToBeChanged` with `newData` (se also log after 4 seconds). As i understood from [vue guid](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) it should to update also the input value but it doens't, and i don't understand why, because `dataToBeChanged` have now the new values from `newData`. Can someone explain me why  and how should i do to make it work?

**Here i'm using the the Parent:**

```
import Parent from "./parent.js";

Vue.component("app", {
  components: {
    Parent
  },
  template: `
           <div>
             <parent :inputsData="{
                                   'firstElement':{'firstInputValue':'Hi there'},
                                   'secondElement':{'secondInputValue':'Bye there'}
                                    }"></parent>
           </div>
            `
});
```

**Here is the Parent:**

```
import Child from "./child.js";
export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  props: {
    inputsData: Object
  },
  template: ` 
         <div>
           <child @focusEvent="handleFocusFromChild"
                  :value.sync="inputsData.firstElement.firstInputValue"></child>
           <child @focusEvent="handleFocusFromChild"  
                  :value.sync="inputsData.secondElement.secondInputValue"></child>
           </div>
            `,
  computed: {
    dataToBeChanged: {
      get: function() {
        return this.inputsData;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.$emit("update:inputsData", newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleFocusFromChild: function() {
      var newData = {
        firstElement: { firstInputValue: "Hi there is changed" },
        secondElement: { secondInputValue: "Bye there is changed" }
      };
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.dataToBeChanged = newData;
      }, 3000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(this.dataToBeChanged);
      }, 4000);
    }
  }
};
```

**Here is the child:**

```
export default {
  template: `
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input @focus="$emit('focusEvent', $event)"
                         v-model="value">
                </div>
              </div>
            `,
  props: {
    value: String
  }
};
```

Comment: You should not use a prop as v-model. Props should be read-only

Comment: @Seblor but if i need that as prop how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at that article : https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-7b127b9bca5b

Comment: @Seblor thx for that, i readed this before, but it doesn't help me. If you konw how to help me then make please an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you child component should emit "this.$emit('update:value', newValue)" as event
take a look over the docs: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Also a way to do it is like this:

```
export default {
  template: `
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input @focus="$emit('focusEvent', $event)"
                         v-model="valueProp">
                </div>
              </div>
            `,
  props: {
    value: String
  },
  computed: {
    valueProp:{
            get(){
                return this.value
            },

            set(val){
                return this.$emit("update:value", val);
            }
        },
  }
  methods: {
    handleFocus() {
      this.$emit("focusEvent");
    }
  }
};
```